# Unable to connect to visible wireless network

Tags: wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and I'm unable to use my wifi router. I see my wireless networkname in the network menu and when I select it and type my password, it tries for several seconds to connect and then fails. I'm sure the password is correct, because I use it with no problem with my Windows 8 OS on the same machine. When I connect my notebook to the router via cable it works fine (actually I'm using it now that way). So why I cannot connect to the wifi network?

Ubuntu 13.04 64bit
Lenovo G580

**EDIT**

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: b8:88:e3:94:bf:12
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.101 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:d3900000-d393ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: c0:14:3d:d3:ca:7f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:d3800000-d3803fff
```

**EDIT 2**

```
$ dmesg
[ 4171.962758] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 4171.965750] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 4171.965752] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 4171.965754] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 4171.965755] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 4171.965756] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 4171.965757] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 4171.965758] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Network Manager often has trouble working with Broadcom.

I like to use WICD because it is a simple and easy to use network manager. Its a very good alternative to network manager in Ubuntu and it seems to always work when Network Manager doesn't. To install it just open up the terminal.

To download and install WICD

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
```

And now you need to uninstall NetworkManager:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

Now you can find WICD in your menu Start WICD, find the network you want to use and enter the information needed, password, encryption, etcetera and choose Automatically Connect to this network. You should be good to go!

WICD may also be available in Ubuntu Update Manager so you can look there first but it is important to uninstall Network Manager completely to prevent conflicts!!